# Is it possible to assign a function to a variable, then trigger it with scope?

Tags: angularjs

I have a function that is assigned to a variable. I then assign this variable to `$scope` with the hope that it will call the function. But it doesn't work:

```
var func = myFunction("argument");
$scope.func;
```

I also tried:

```
var func = myFunction("argument");
$scope[func];
```

Is there a way I can get this to work?

Answer (score 4):

You have a few things missing:

```
    var someFn = function (arg) {
           //do something with arg
    }
```

You can then add this function to the scope:

```
$scope.fnOnScope = someFn;
```

You can then execute the function:

```
$scope.fnOnScope("argument");
```

Alternatively, you can just put the function on the scope in the first place.

Comment: I made a few mistakes when formulating my question. The variable ``func`` is assigned to text, not a function. But, this text represents a function. That's why I want to assign it to ``$scope``.

Comment: Oh, I understand.  So, func is assigned a string value that is the name of a function, correct?  If this function is on the scope, you can execute it with $scope[func]();  The function to execute must be defined on the scope for this work.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds a little dangerous (evaluating the function to execute "on the fly") but assuming that's what you want, it should be fairly easy if you place the function on an object.

```
var availableFunctions = {
   functionToCall: function(arg) {
      console.log(arg);
   }
};

var func = myFunction("argument"); // assume this returns "functionToCall" 
$scope.func = availableFunctions[func];
```

Is that closer to what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

If the `func` is the name of the function that's already declared in window scope. Try:

```
var func = myFunction("argument");
window[func].call($scope);
```